# shake action catched in other views?

Tags: iphone, view, uinavigationcontroller, accelerometer, pushviewcontroller

I have a simple app which consists of 2 views. Top view has a accelerometer delegates. when user shakes while top view is on the screen. then pushviewcontroller is called and subview will appear. the problem is when subview is appeard, i shake it, it still catches the shake action and results me an error. So help me. thanks in advance.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
const float violence = 1.2;
static BOOL beenhere;
BOOL shake = FALSE;

if (beenhere) return;
beenhere = TRUE;

if (acceleration.x > violence || acceleration.x < (-1* violence))
    shake = TRUE;
if (acceleration.y > violence || acceleration.y < (-1* violence))
    shake = TRUE;
if (acceleration.z > violence || acceleration.z < (-1* violence))
    shake = TRUE;
if (shake) {
    [self playSound:@"suzu"];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"noVib"] == NO) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:mMoviePlayer animated:YES];
    [self play]; 
}
```

when play method called and video has finished, pushviewcontroller will be called and the sub view will appear

below is a class that handles all the movieplayer stuff.

```
- (void) initPlayer{
if (mMoviePlayer != nil){
    [mMoviePlayer release];
}

mMoviePlayer = [[MoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self createURL]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:mMoviePlayer 
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer];
[mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mMoviePlayer.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer];

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
```

{

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];        
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:mMoviePlayer.moviePlayer];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[mMoviePlayer release];
mMoviePlayer = nil;
[self toNext];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes into my mind is to keep track if the mMoviePlayer is pushed or not.

```
if (shake && mPlayerPushed) {
    [self playSound:@"suzu"];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"noVib"] == NO) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:mMoviePlayer animated:YES];
    [self play]; 
    mPlayerPushed = YES;
}
```

in the moviePlayBackDidFinish method after you call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES you should set the mPlayerPushed to NO.

or you could use the property modal view controller to see if a modal view is displayed. This i haven't tested yet but it should work.

> modalViewController: The controller for the active modal view—that is,
>   the view that is temporarily displayed on top of the view managed by
>   the receiver. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *modalViewController
```

so instead of the bool mPlayerPushed you will have:

```
if(shake && something.modalviewController == nil){ present mMoviePlayer }
```

Comment: you should test if the modalViewController property is equal to your mMoviePlayer if that is true then you could use it instead of declaring a new variable like in the initial idea i had. The first solution though should work as expected.

Comment: i changed the condition to shake &&mMoviePlayer. So the subview doesn`t catch (or something ??) the shake action. but when the subview  appears cache is displayed on the subview.in other words, i shake it , then i go back to main menu again, then i shake it again, this time subview instantly showed me earlier contents of subivew then it quichly changed to correct view. what does it mean ?

Comment: i checked self.modalviewController == mmovieplayer. but it is not equal

Comment: the condition if(shake && mMoviePlayer) will not work for you because from what i see you initialize mMoviePlayer before that condition is checked. So mMoviePlayer will always be different of nil so you will always enter the if block. Try to add a new bool variable like in the first code snippet i added.

Comment: well thanks Sorin Antohi, your code snipped is working, tough i didn`t understand all what you mean.

Comment: could you tell me What does movieplayer pushed has something to do the shake action?

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with the shake action. it is just a check that is made in order not to push another mMoviePlayer on top of an existing one. It is weird though that the UIAccelerometer still calls the delegate methods although you set it to nil. maybe you set it again to self in another part.. after the mMoviePlayer is pushed or something..